# Message printing after I apt-get install or needrestart about services, containers, user sessions and VMs

Tags: apt, linux-kernel, containers

I've just put Ubuntu 22.04 on my server, and when I execute `apt-get install x`(where `x` a package I want to download) or `needrestart`, I get this message that I haven't found an explanation for.

```
Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

Also, after the last line (`No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.`), it has some delay before I can type another command.

Any help as to what it means and why it appears would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells you what needs to be restarted for the updates to be effective. In this case, nothing.

The behavior depends on the setting `$nrconf{restart}` in `/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf`

- `i`: prompt interactively for restarts (default value)
- `a`: restart automatically
- `l`: list needed restarts

See this question and answers for details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139/apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services

Comment: Oh, so it's a heads-up in case a service that needs restarting got omitted for some reason?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Great, thank you! Do you perhaps have any idea as to how a similar message would appear, with the difference that it would ask for something to be restarted?